# Django вывод в шаблоны

Tags: django, django-orm, django-model

Подскажите пожалуйста как вывести в шаблон несколько моделей в шаблон.
Есть такие модели

```
class MonitorModel(Model):
diagonal = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Диоганаль')
photo = models.ImageField(blank=True,null=True)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Модель монитора'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Модели мониторов'

def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class Monitor(Product):
model = models.ForeignKey(MonitorModel, models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Модель монитора')

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Монитор'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Мониторы'

def __str__(self):
    return self.serialNumber


class HeadsetModel(Model):
photo = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Модель гарнитуры'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Модели гарнитур'

def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class Headset(Product):
model = models.ForeignKey(HeadsetModel, models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Модель гарнитуры')

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Гарнитура'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Гарнитуры'

def __str__(self):
    return self.serialNumber


class SpeakersModel(Model):
photo = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Модель колонок'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Модели колонок'

def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class Speakers(Product):
model = models.ForeignKey(SpeakersModel, models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Динамиков')

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Колонки'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Колонки'

def __str__(self):
    return self.serialNumber
```

во view следующие классы:

```
class OutputsView(TemplateView):
template_name = 'outputs/outputs_info.html'


class MonitorList(ListView):
model = Monitor
queryset = Monitor.objects.all()
template_name = 'outputs/outputsList.html'
context_object_name = 'monitor'


class HeadsetList(ListView):
model = Headset
queryset = Headset.objects.all()
template_name = 'outputs/outputsList.html'
context_object_name = 'headSet'
```

в URL:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', login_required(OutputsView.as_view()),      name='outputs_info'),
path('list/', login_required(MonitorList.as_view()), name='output_list'),
path('list/', login_required(HeadsetList.as_view()), name='output_list'),
]
```

В шаблонах:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block  header %}
    {% include 'header.html' %}
{% endblock %}

{% block title %}Список устройств{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

    <div class="container">
        <h3 class="List-title">Список устройств</h3>
        {% if messages %}
            {% for message in messages %}
                <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }} alert-dismissible fade in show" role="alert">
                    {{ message|safe }}
                    <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="col"><p class="count">Общее колличество: {{ pl.count }}</p></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col"></div>
            <div class="col">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-light">
                    <form action="{% url 'printer_list' %}" method="get" class="form-inline">
                        <input name="q" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search"
                               aria-label="Search">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                    </form>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <a href="{% url 'printer_create' %}">Добавить</a>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th> Серийный номер</th>
                <th> Тип устройства</th>
                <th>Модель </th>
                <th>Производитель</th>
                <th scope="col">Действие</th>

            </tr>
            {% for m in monitor %}
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ m.serialNumber }}</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            {% endfor %}


            {% for hs in headSet %}
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ hs.serialNumber }}</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
{% block footer %}
{% endblock %}
```

А теперь внимание вопрос:
Как в шаблоны вывести все устройства в один список. В настоящее время выводится только список по одной модели а как сделать что бы этих моделей было не одна?

Comment: возможно вам сможет помочь вот это приложение https://pypi.org/project/django-querysetsequence/

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял задачу, Вы хотите перебрать несколько моделей на одном темплейте, поправьте если я не прав.

В таком случае можно просто создать context, который потом разобрать в темплейте.

то есть View будет выглядеть так:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import View


class SomeProductView(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        model_1 = Model_1.objects.all()
        model_2 = Model_2.objects.all()
        model_3 = Model_3.objects.all()
        # и т.д.
    
        context = {
            'model_1': model_1,
            'model_2': model_2,
            'model_3': model_3,
         }
        return render(request, 'ИМЯ_ТЕМПЛЕЙТ_ФАЙЛА.html', context)
```

В Urls.py ничего нового:

```
бла бла бла...
path('someproducts/', SomeProductsView.as_view(), name='some_products'),
...
```

Теперь в темплейте они доступны по переменным model_1, model_2 и т.д. из переданного context.

Надеюсь я правильно понял задачу...